# Inject data into scope without <template>

Tags: vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to get rid of two lines in the html used in a vue 2.x application. The lines with `<template scope="props">` and the corresponding `</template>` should not be necessary.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <my-component>
    <template scope="props">
      <p>{{props.test}}</p>
    </template>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

I would rather define my own component attribute to define the scope name

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <my-component with="props">
    <p>{{props.test}}</p>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

So instead of exposing the writer of the HTML to the concepts of `templates` and `scopes` we would do that inside `my-component`.

Does anybody know whether the vue templating mechanism is open for extension inside components like this ?

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of having component is that it can be re-used at multiple places. so idea is to define `template` at one place and you can use it at multiple places.

the example you have written, you will be able to re-use it at again. template of component is generally not defined inside component, it will be separate and than that component can be used at multiple places.

See one sample below:

```
<div id="app">
  <template id="item-edit">
    <li>
      <span v-show="!inEdit">{{item.name}}</span>
      <input v-show="inEdit" type="text" v-model="item.name" />
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggle();">{{inEdit ? 'save' : 'edit'}}</a>
    </li>
  </template>
  <ul>
    <item-edit v-for="item in items" :item="item"></item-edit>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Complete fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/corh2tqo/

Comment: I understand but we dont use templates like that at all. We just need this as a transclusion scope.

i.e we allow designers to live write some designs. in those it is sometimes helpful to reference data dynamically.

    <rs-get id="some-data-id-to-lookup" as="localVarName">
        <strong>{{localVarName.fullName}}</strong>
    </rs-get>

in these cases the inner template is still part of the outer scope usually just with some injected extra information. There is no need for re-use at all.

PS: Why do comments on answers not get formatted the same way ? :)

Comment: @mgoetzke If you are not using components anywhere else, than you can just write plain HTML itself, and dont make those components, why to increase complexity for no additional gain.

Comment: we need data binding to the components as sen in the example the outer component data is bound and augmented  in the  my-component children